# How to read json string in c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to parse manually a string in json. This is how my json look like

```
{{
  "dbViews": [
    {
      "viewID": 0,
      "viewColumns": [
        {
          "dbTitle": "ColNmid",
          "viewTitle": "string",
          "activated": true,
          "activatedLabel": "Afficher"
        },
        {
          "dbTitle": "ColNmdelete",
          "viewTitle": "string",
          "activated": true,
          "activatedLabel": "Afficher"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "AddViewName": "test"
}}
```

This is how i am trying to read it.

```
            UserViewDto User = new UserViewDto();
            dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
            User.id = obj.dbViews.viewID;
            User.viewName = obj.AddViewName;

            foreach (var item in obj.viewColumns)
            {
                if (obj.dbTitle == "ColNmid")
                {
                    User.ColNmid = obj.viewTitle;
                }
            }
```

I can only read addViewName, i can't seem to access viewID or viewColumn.

**Update:**

after the comments I obviously miss the second array. Here my new code witch work

```
            UserViewDto User = new UserViewDto();
            dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);

            User.viewName = obj.AddViewName;

            foreach (var view in obj.dbViews)
            {
                User.id = view.viewID;              

                foreach (var item in view.viewColumns)
                {
                    if (item.dbTitle == "ColNmid")
                    {
                        User.ColNmid = item.viewTitle;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: that isn't valid json _and_ dbviews is an array.

Comment: `dbViews` is array, not an object. Also why just not `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserViewDto>();` or another model which matches your json?

Comment: Please read [ask]. What does _"i can't seem to access viewID or viewColumn"_ mean, what happens **exactly**?

Comment: If i use deserializeobject<userviewDto> I would need to create a custom model, witch i dont feel like writing, would my foreach for each object not work?

Comment: Yes, `foreach()` would work, but you need another one. As @Guru said, `dbViews` is in itself also an array.

Comment: Also `viewColumns` is also an array.

Comment: *witch [sic] i dont feel like writing*  Let Visual Studio do it for you **Edit** menu -> **Paste Special** -> **Paste Json as classes**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json in question is invalid (extra `{` and `}` at start and end). It seems that you are using Newtonsoft's Json.NET library. Usual approach is to create model corresponding to your json structure and deserialize it:

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("dbViews")]
    public List<DbView> DbViews { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AddViewName")]
    public string AddViewName { get; set; }
}

public class DbView
{
    [JsonProperty("viewID")]
    public long ViewId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("viewColumns")]
    public List<ViewColumn> ViewColumns { get; set; }
}

public class ViewColumn
{
    [JsonProperty("dbTitle")]
    public string DbTitle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("viewTitle")]
    public string ViewTitle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("activated")]
    public bool Activated { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("activatedLabel")]
    public string ActivatedLabel { get; set; }
} 

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>();
```

You don't need to include all properties in your class, you can include only needed ones.

If you don't want to create custom models and want to loop through the `JObject` properties in your case you can do it for example like that:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach(var view in jObj["dbViews"]) // dbViews is an array
{
    Console.WriteLine(view["viewID"]);
    foreach (var viewColumn in view["viewColumns"]) // viewColumns is an array
    {
        Console.WriteLine(viewColumn["dbTitle"]);
    }
}
```